# Is it possible to alter /Update Expiration time in Azure Queue?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-queues

Is it possible to alter /Update Expiration time from 7 days to 10 days or 7 days to 1 day in Azure Queue?

What is the use of PopReceipt and Next Visible field in Azure Queue?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Yes, when you [put a message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179346.aspx) on the queue you can specify a `messagettl` value for the number of seconds before the message expires and is automatically removed.  The maximum allowed value is 7 days, which is also the default.

If you're using the .NET SDK then you can pass this as a TimeSpan `timeToLive` argument into the [CloudQueue.AddMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.queue.cloudqueue.addmessage.aspx) method.

The **PopReceipt** is an identifier that's used when a message is retrieved and is used by clients to subsequently delete a message once it's been processed.  The **NextVisible** time is also used when a message is retrieved, to indicate when the message will become visible again to all other clients, if it's not first deleted by the client that retrieved it.

Comment: The question asked if you can update the time, not if you can set it when initially writing to the queue